# Referencing lables from a separate lyx document

Tags: cross-reference

I am trying to refer to a figure in another lyx document. In tex, one can use the xr package and declare another document in /externaldocument, and, if you are careful, the label will transfer. In lyx, under the cross-reference menu, you can, in principle, add a label from another lyx document. However, the cross reference says BROKEN:... and the label doesn't appear in the derived pdf. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Absolutely ridiculous that there is no support for this.